# How to use DISTINCT ON but ORDER BY another expression?

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct-on

The model `Subscription` `has_many` `SubscriptionCart`.

A `SubscriptionCart` has a `status` and an `authorized_at` date.

I need to pick the cart with the oldest `authorized_at` date from all the carts associated to a `Subscription`, and then I have to order all the returned `Subscription` results by this `subscription_carts.authorized_at` column.

**The query below is working but I can't figure out how to select `DISTINCT ON subscription.id` to avoid duplicates but `ORDER BY subscription_carts.authorized_at` .**

raw sql query so far:

```
select distinct on (s.id) s.id as subscription_id, subscription_carts.authorized_at, s.*
from subscriptions s
join subscription_carts subscription_carts on subscription_carts.subscription_id = s.id 
and subscription_carts.plan_id = s.plan_id
where subscription_carts.status = 'processed'
and s.status IN ('authorized','in_trial', 'paused')
order by s.id, subscription_carts.authorized_at
```

If I try to `ORDER BY subscription_carts.authorized_at` first, I get an error because the `DISTINCT ON` and `ORDER BY` expressions must be in the same order.

The solutions I've found seem too complicated for what I need and I've failed to implement them because I don't understand them fully.

Would it be better to `GROUP BY subscription_id` and then pick from that group instead of using `DISTINCT ON`? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Use a subquery and order on the end result

Comment: Could you be more specific? A subquery for selecting the min authorized_at date from a group of subscription_carts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requirement is necessary to make `DISTINCT ON` work; to change the final order, you can add an outer query with another `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (s.id)
             s.id as subscription_id, subscription_carts.authorized_at, s.*
      FROM subscriptions s
         JOIN ...
      WHERE ...
      ORDER BY s.id, subscription_carts.authorized_at
     ) AS subq
ORDER BY authorized_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `DISTINCT ON`. While it is occasionally useful, I personally find window function based approaches much more clear:

```sql
-- Optionally, list all columns explicitly, to remove the rn column again
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    s.id AS subscription_id,
    c.authorized_at,
    s.*,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY s.id ORDER BY c.authorized_at) rn
  FROM subscriptions s
  JOIN subscription_carts c
  ON c.subscription_id = s.id
  AND c.plan_id = s.plan_id
  WHERE c.status = 'processed'
  AND s.status IN ('authorized', 'in_trial', 'paused')
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY subscription_id, authorized_at
```